# Errors in levels of subtable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, levels

here is my problem : 
I have a table with 3 columns and 12 raws that looks like this :[image]

when I execute : 
data$exp, I get : 
h h h h h h U U U U U U

Levels: h U
(what I expect).

But When I execute 
cordata[1:6,]$exp

I get:  h h h h h;

Levels: h U.

I don't understand why I still got U in the levels since I took only the first 6 raws.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: try the `droplevels`

Comment: Thanks akrun! sorry for duplicate question

Comment: It's okay.  Someitmes it is difficult to find if we don't use the correct keywords.  Yesterday, I spent many hours to find a jQuery stuff as I ddin't use the correct keyword